# Grammar Question about correct tense use in context

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Please, help me with that that kind of construction:

The action had started in the past, been in progress, now is in progress and will be in progress untill exact time period.

For example:

I've started watching Tv at 9 a.m.
I've been watching it for a while.
I am now watching it.
I will watch it untill 2 p.m

I guess, I can use present perfect continious and than add another verb.

```
I have been watching the TV since 9 a.m. and I will be watching it untill 2 p.m..
```

Let's try out another one:

Let's say that the Product team has to make a decision by the end of April whether the computer program should be changed. And they have already started to thinking about that.
So, how this sentence should be done showing the process had already started? And it is going on right now and will be completed by the end of April?

Can we do that with one time construction?

I guess, we can try out this:

```
The decision to change the programm has been making by the Product team. It will be in progress until the end of April.
```

Can we do that with one time construstion?
or
Is there any possibility to make the grammar construction using only one verb?

Can we say that:

```
The Product team is considering whether is to change the program until the end of April.
```

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different ideas: they have started considering, and they will decide by the end of April. I don't see how to say that with just one verb.

"The product team is considering changes to the program, and they will make their decision by the end of April."